# Dialogflow - Google Assistant: setFollowupEvent after showing a message

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Here it is my use case: somewhere in my fulfillment, while handling the Intent A, I want to call Intent B using `setFollowupEvent`. Something like:

```
function intentA_Handler(){
    ....
    agent.add('This is the response when calling Intent A');
    agent.setFollowupEvent('call_intent_B_event');
}

function intentB_Handler(){
    agent.add('I am in intent B now.');
    ....
}
```

What I'm expecting:

1. The assistant Shows & Speaks out the string **This is the response when calling Intent A**
2. Then calling `agent.setFollowupEvent('call_intent_B_event');` and Showing & Speaking out the string **I am in intent B now.**

What happens:

The assistant immediately shows & speaks out to me the string **I am in intent B now** and omits the first string **This is the response when calling Intent A**

Already tried:

```
function intentA_Handler(){
    ....
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        agent.add('This is the response when calling Intent A');
        resolve();
    });

    agent.setFollowupEvent('call_intent_B_event');
}
```

But still the same result. Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: have you got this working by any chance? i am stuck at the same case where  I am in intent B now  is fired and omits This is the response when calling Intent A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The followup event goes back to Dialogflow and not the Actions on Google platform. The second intent response will go back to the assistant as the only response coming from the agent.

If you use the Actions on Google client library (https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview), the it has a way to pass parameters with the follow up event: https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#followup
You could use the parameter values to track additional information you want to include in the final response.

Comment: In the 2nd link it shows how to send parameters with `followup` method but, it doesn't show how to access those parameters in the called **intent**, and I couldn't find anything in the internet. Do you have any link about this?

Comment: The parameters are handled in the same way as usual. In Dialogflow you can extract the parameter values or pass it on to fulfillment which can use an intent handler with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In general - you don't need to use followup events if you are doing things through fulfillment. Remember - Intents usually represent the *user* doing or saying something, **not** what you want the reply to be.

If you need to  call some code in both the Intent Handler for A and for B - just call that code as another function. If you want to conclude with the same message in both A and B - then you can just call `add()` with the messages you want in both A and B - either directly or by calling a common function. Perhaps something like this:

```
function addMessageB(){
    agent.add('This was from adding message B.');
}

function intentA_Handler(){
    ....
    agent.add('This is the response when calling Intent A');
    addMessageB();
}

function intentB_Handler(){
    addMessageB();
    ....
}
```

There are limitations (you can only `add()` two Simple Messages, for example), but this would be the general approach.

Comment: I'm having this problem know, and what you say makes it impossible to use the responses from within DialogFlow UI.
What I do, I make a response in DialogFlow like : "Your data is ${data}.", and in the webhook `agent.add(<consoleMessage with regexp replacement>)`. Now the client can use the DialogFlow UI to set the messages, and I can add the data with the code.

Comment: This didn't solve the question! , we need to followUp an user response with followupEvent but the problem is that we can't use agent.add with this method.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use a followupEvent? (Perhaps elaborate on this as a new question?) Based on the original question here, the needs were to have two sets of responses from different handlers. The notion that these have to be from different Intents is a common misunderstanding of what an Intent is in Dialogflow and how followupEvents work.